# Twilio Programmable Video Using Javascript

Tags: javascript, .net, twilio, twilio-video

working js file twilio-video.js: 1.14.1.
all code working in single page .aspx file.

if possible participant audio track disable share code.

```
//Participant is all participant connect with Room. For Ex. User-1 Screen Page Participant User-2, User-3 And User-4.

participant.audioTracks.forEach(function (track) {
if (track.kind === 'audio') {
   track.mediaStreamTrack.enabled = false;
   track.mediaStreamTrack.muted = true;
}


// sid is disable Audio track Particular Participant sid. For Ex. User-1 Screen Participant User-3 audio disable using audio track sid It is Possible. If Possible give me code or reference url link.

if (track.sid == sid)
{
     //participant audio track disable.
    track.disable();
}
});
```

If it is possible give me code or url reference link.

It is possible User-3 screen only user-1 video and audio unable and disable. User-3 screen user-3 as localparticipant and user-1 as remoteparticipant.

If another way it's possible give me suggestion and reference url link. 
If Rest Api Possible Give me reference url link i am refer Twilio rest api.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The [reference documentation for the Twilio Video JavaScript SDK is available here](https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/video/releases/1.14.1/docs/LocalParticipant.html).

You can only disable `LocalTrack`s in the SDK, for example [`LocalAudioTrack#disable`](https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/video/releases/1.14.1/docs/LocalAudioTrack.html#disable__anchor).

I'm not sure what else you're asking here. Is your code not working as expected or throwing an error?

Comment: Yes Participant audio is enable and disable. I am do this.

Answer (score 0):

my scenario is User-1, User-2 And User-3 Connect Same Room And All User Audio Disable. User-1 Screen User-1 As localparticipant and user-2 and user-3 As remoteparticipant Same As User-2 Screen And User-3 Screen.

But User-1 Screen All remoteparticipant video Enable and User-2 And User-3 Screen Only Self view And Participant Video Not Display.

User-1 can Start Communication with User-2 That Time User-1 Audio Enable And User-2 Audio Enable only this two user can Audio And Video communicate With Each Other. Like One To One Not One To Many.

For Ex. User-1 Can Start Button That Time User-1 Local Audio Enable And User-2 
Local Audio Enable. But Currently Issue User-3 Can hear User-1 and User-2 Communication Audio I Want Disable Audio. It Is Possible?

**User-3 Screen all Participant Audio Disable It Is Possible?**

**If User-1 screen localparticipant audio enable but user-3 screen user-1 as remoteparticipant i want to user-1 participant audio disable. it is possible?**

**It's Possible Javascipt code Audio Will disable?
All are doing in same page using .net and javascript.**

If it is Possible show my code.